# Is it possible to simplify jQuery string for toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have page with more icons and when you click on the icon you can see div where is some content. I would like to know if it is possible to write it somehow more simple then I do. I have 10 icons and I want to have always only one Div opened, so jQuery is quite long and 10 times almost the same.

**This is how my jQuery looks like for 1 icon. It is almost the same for rest of them**

```
$(".icon_pl").click(function(){
    $("div#show").hide("slow");
    $("div#rockz").hide("slow");
    $("div#join").hide("slow");
    $("div#wedding").hide("slow");
    $("div#pl").toggle("slow");
    if ($(this).hasClass('icon_active'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('icon_active')
        } else {
    $('.icon_active').removeClass('icon_active');
    $(this).toggleClass("icon_active");}
    return false;
});
```

**Icons**

```
<div class="iconteiner">
        <ul>
            <li><span class="icon_pl"></span><h3>Private Lesson</h3></li>
            <li><span class="icon_join"></span><h3>Join Us</h3></li>
            <li><span class="icon_wedding"></span><h3>Wedding Dance</h3></li>
            <li><span class="icon_rockz"></span><h3>ROKCZ Couture</h3></li>
            <li><span class="icon_show"></span><h3>Show Dance</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Divs with content**

```
        <div class="content">
        <div id="pl">
            <h2>Headlin 1</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="join">
            <h2>Headlin 2</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="wedding">
            <h2>Headline 3</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="rockz">
            <h2>Headline 4</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="show">
            <h2>Headline 5</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works, but I would like to know if it is possible to make it somehow more simple and to write down every id (each div is different with different content, this is why id and not class)

Thank you

Comment: Can you add this to a fiddle as i think so this will not work or you have missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. Note the selector is the LI since the span has no content

Actually Can you change the class on the span to ID or DATA attribute so one can always use 
 `$span.attr("id").split("_")[1];` or  `$span.data("div2show");`

```
$(function() {
  $(".iconteiner li").on("click", function() {
    $(".content > div").hide("slow");
    var $span = $(this).find("span");
    var id = $span.attr("class").split("_")[1];
    $("#" + id).show("slow");
    $span.toggleClass('icon_active');
  });
});
```

```js
    $(function() {
      $(".iconteiner li").on("click", function() {
        $(".content > div").hide("slow");
        var $span = $(this).find("span");
        var id = $span.attr("class").split("_")[1];
        $("#" + id).show("slow");
        $span.toggleClass('icon_active');
      });
    });
```

```css
.content div {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iconteiner">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="icon_pl"></span>
      <h3>Private Lesson</h3>
    </li>
    <li><span class="icon_join"></span>
      <h3>Join Us</h3>
    </li>
    <li><span class="icon_wedding"></span>
      <h3>Wedding Dance</h3>
    </li>
    <li><span class="icon_rockz"></span>
      <h3>ROKCZ Couture</h3>
    </li>
    <li><span class="icon_show"></span>
      <h3>Show Dance</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
Divs with content
<div class="content">
  <div id="pl">
    <h2>Headlin 1</h2>
    <p class="product_description"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="join">
    <h2>Headlin 2</h2>
    <p class="product_description"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="wedding">
    <h2>Headline 3</h2>
    <p class="product_description"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="rockz">
    <h2>Headline 4</h2>
    <p class="product_description"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="show">
    <h2>Headline 5</h2>
    <p class="product_description"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference here betwen writing the selector as you've done and this `$(".iconteiner > li > span")`?

Comment: That you can click any part of the LI now. The Span has no content. But thanks for letting me look again and toggle the span class. Now of course I need to find the right class

Comment: Awsome. Thank you very much. I am really beginner with jQuery, but i will learn from this a lot. Thank you. :)

Comment: I have a question. Now as I ad function if with class_active it works perfect. It even works when I put for example `<span class="icon_show">` into the hidden div. So it means that `var $span = $(this).find("span");` find all span in code? and how is that possible that it hides the div when we have ` $(".iconteiner li").on("click", function()`; it means that you have to click somewhere in the icontainer or not? It is GOOD that it works like that, just want to know how is that possible :) thank you

Comment: The selector targets all LI in iconteiner so the whole LI is clickable. Then I find the span in the clicked LI

Answer (score 1):

you could put the name of the relating div in either a rel attribute or in a data prefixed attribute

then in JS/Jquery hide all of the divs, and only show the one you need - that relates to the new attribute.

something along the lines of

```
$(".icon").click(function(){
$(".maindivs div").hide();
var toggleDiv = $(this).attr("data-divToToggle");
$("#"+toggleDiv ).slideDown("slow");

   if ($(this).hasClass('icon_active'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('icon_active')
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('.icon_active').removeClass('icon_active');
        $(this).toggleClass("icon_active");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That's what I would do. Note that jQuery has a method to get data attributes directly (`$(selector).data(key)`): https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

Following script would do what you expect.

```
$(function () {

    //hide all div on load except first one
    $('div.content div:not(#pl)').hide();

    $("li.icon").click(function () {
        var div = $(this).data('div');

        $('div.content div.icon_active')
            .removeClass('icon_active')
            .hide('slow');

        $('div.content div#' + div)
            .addClass('icon_active')
            .show('slow');

        return false;
    });
});
```

Your HTML would look something liek this.

```
<div class="iconteiner">
    <ul>
        <li class='icon' data-div='pl'><span class="icon_pl"></span>
            <h3>Private Lesson</h3>
        </li>
        <li class='icon' data-div='join'><span class="icon_join"></span>
            <h3>Join Us</h3>
        </li>
        <li class='icon' data-div='wedding'><span class="icon_wedding"></span>
            <h3>Wedding Dance</h3>
        </li>
        <li class='icon' data-div='rockz'><span class="icon_rockz"></span>
            <h3>ROKCZ Couture</h3>
        </li>
        <li class='icon' data-div='show'><span class="icon_show"></span>
            <h3>Show Dance</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="pl" class="icon_active">
         <h2>Headlin 1</h2>

        <p class="product_description"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="join">
         <h2>Headlin 2</h2>

        <p class="product_description"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="wedding">
         <h2>Headline 3</h2>

        <p class="product_description"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="rockz">
         <h2>Headline 4</h2>

        <p class="product_description"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="show">
         <h2>Headline 5</h2>

        <p class="product_description"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is [WORKING JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/npdakzow/)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the elements are related hierarchically, I'd add a data attribute to be able to easily find the correct content.

```js
 $(function() {
    $('li[data-content]').click(function(){
      $('li[data-content] span').removeClass('icon-active');
      $(this).find('span').addClass('icon-active');
      $('.content div').hide();
      $('.content div[id='+$(this).data('content')+']').show();
    });
  });
```

```css
.content div {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="iconteiner">
        <ul>
            <li data-content='pl'><span class="icon_pl"></span><h3>Private Lesson</h3></li>
            <li data-content='join'><span class="icon_join"></span><h3>Join Us</h3></li>
            <li data-content='wedding'><span class="icon_wedding"></span><h3>Wedding Dance</h3></li>
            <li data-content='rockz'><span class="icon_rockz"></span><h3>ROKCZ Couture</h3></li>
            <li data-content='show'><span class="icon_show"></span><h3>Show Dance</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 
     <div class="content">
        <div id="pl">
            <h2>Headlin 1</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="join">
            <h2>Headlin 2</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="wedding">
            <h2>Headline 3</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="rockz">
            <h2>Headline 4</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="show">
            <h2>Headline 5</h2>
            <p class="product_description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```